# How to consume Destination from NodeJS in SAP Cloud Platform

Tags: node.js, odata, cloud-foundry, sap-cloud-platform

I have nodeJS running in SAP Cloud Platform Cloud foundry and an oData destination (oData in cloud, not on premise) created in the Cloud foundry sub account level.

My question is how can I consume this oData destination (oData in cloud, not on premise) from Node.JS.

Appreciate your response

Regards
Shanmukha Rao

Comment: Are you building your nodeJs module in the Web IDE FS as part of a MTA project?
Can you elaborate on your context?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to bind the service instance of your destination to the application and then consume the destination in dest-app.json of your application as in the [blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/10/16/call-sap-cloud-platform-cloud-foundry-destinations-from-your-node.js-application/)

Comment: I know it's a long blog post but, if possible, including the relevant information in your answer makes it a better answer, in case of 404s, and the like. Just a suggestion though - it's not mandatory.